# Default placeholder for missing fields doesn't work with block in xtract tool

Tags: bash, edirect

I am using the [xtract tool](https://dataguide.nlm.nih.gov/edirect/xtract.html) of the Entrez Direct ([EDirect](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/)) package of NBCI. I have a list of Accession Numbers:

```
U47804, U47803, U47802, U47801, U47800, U47799, U47798, X92938
```

and try to get information about:

1. Name of organism (Org-ref_taxname tag)
2. Product of gene (Prot-ref_name_E tag)
3. Public year (Date-std_year tag)

I executed the following command:

```bash
for i in {U47804 U47803 U47802 U47801 U47800 U47799 U47798 X92938}
do
  efetch -db "nucleotide" -id "$i" -format full; done |
    xtract -pattern Seq-entry -element Org-ref_taxname \
      -block Prot-ref_name -def "-" -element Prot-ref_name_E \
      -block Date-std -position first -element Date-std_year
```

The result I got:

```
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  1995
```

Because the **X92938** doesn't have *<Prot-ref_name>*, so I was expecting to replace the missing fields with **"-"** by the `-def` tag of the extract tool. It means my desired result is as follows:

```
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1  gp120   1996
Human immunodeficiency virus 1    -     1995
```

Can someone have experience with the NBCI tool may help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I saw this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75469564/default-placeholder-for-missing-fields-doesnt-work-with-block-in-xtract-tool-b) but I couldn't figure out the problem. One of the great things about https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ is that you can include heaps more detail here; if you could please provide more context it might help e.g. Why do you want this data? Have you looked at other sources e.g. [the Rentrez package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rentrez/vignettes/rentrez_tutorial.html)? Could you post-format the data using e.g. `awk`? Etc

Comment: Thanks for your helpful suggestion. According to your suggestion, I have used [Rentrez](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rentrez/vignettes/rentrez_tutorial.html#web_history) and realized it is much easier to use and more powerful than the Entrez bash. So in some special cases like creating bioinformatics pipelines, using bash Entrez is a compulsory thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying myself in many ways, I have found that the method of creating a checkmark column when a desired column is recorded is more efficient and easier to understand.

Here is my bash script to solve my problem in a verbose way (I guess has others way shorter).

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

change_index(){
    local in="$(< /dev/stdin)" # Variable assignment from the stdin
    local col_num=$(head -n 1 <(echo "$in") |awk -F"\t" '{print -1+NF/2}')  # Number of fields

    
    for k in $(seq 0 $(($col_num-1))); do # Loop through number of field
        in=$(awk -v ia="$k" -F"\t"  '{sub("/[^"ia"]","/"ia"\t-\t/"((ia+1)),$(2*ia+1)) ;print $0}' <(echo "$in")) # Supplement missing fields
    done
    
    in=$(awk -v ia="$col_num" -F"\t"  '{sub("/[^"ia"]","/"ia"\t-",$(2*ia+1)) ;print $0}' <(echo "$in")) # Supplement missing the last fields
    in=$(sed 's/\/[[:digit:]]\+//g' <(echo "$in")) # Remove markers
    echo "$in"
}

for i in {U47804 U47803 U47802 U47801 U47800 U47799 U47798 X92938}; do \
    efetch -db "nucleotide" -id "$i" -format full; done |    
    xtract -pattern Seq-entry \
        -lbl "/0" -element Org-ref_taxname \
        -block Prot-ref_name -lbl "/1" -element Prot-ref_name_E \
        -block Date-std -position first -lbl "/2" -element Date-std_year |
    change_index| column -t
```

### Explanation

The main idea is that if a field is recorded there will be a marker field lay before the recorded field. This action is done by `-lbl` tag. And we have the following draft table:

```
/0  Human  immunodeficiency  virus  1  /1  gp120  /2  1996
/0  Human  immunodeficiency  virus  1  /1  gp120  /2  1996
/0  Human  immunodeficiency  virus  1  /1  gp120  /2  1996
/0  Human  immunodeficiency  virus  1  /1  gp120  /2  1996
/0  Human  immunodeficiency  virus  1  /1  gp120  /2  1996
/0  Human  immunodeficiency  virus  1  /1  gp120  /2  1996
/0  Human  immunodeficiency  virus  1  /1  gp120  /2  1996
/0  Human  immunodeficiency  virus  1  /2  1995
```

After having a draft table, and cleaning the table by `change_index()` function I wrote.